# C++ delete everything in text file that is located before/after a specific word

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text-files

So lets say text file has the following contents:

kasjdfhjkasdhfjkasdhfjasfjs
asdjkfhasj
**start**
sdfjkhasdkjfhasjkdfhajksdfhjkasdfh
asdjfhajs
**end**
sdjfhsjkdf

How to delete everything before the word "start" and everything after "end"?

Comment: Show some research effort of your own.

Comment: And how is this relevant for C++? The simplest way to do this is with tools such as `awk` and `sed` if you are on Unix-like systems.

Comment: @ Baum mit Augen i didnt find any research about what im saying everything talks about delete a specific word or line but not about such thing.

Comment: @ Aaron McDaid im working on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring very specific cases, it is not a good idea to edit files in place. If your computer crashes at the wrong point in time, for instance, you'd end up with a corrupted file and without the ability to restore its state before the attempted transformation.

So, better to read from one file and write to another, which is very simple:

```
std::ifstream in ("input.txt");
std::ofstream out("output.txt");
std::string line;

// read and discard lines before "start"
while(std::getline(in, line) && line != "start");

// read and echo lines until "end"
while(std::getline(in, line) && line != "end") {
  out << line << '\n';
}
```

and then move it to where the original file is, overwriting it. On Windows:

```
MoveFileExA("output.txt", "input.txt", MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

On POSIX-conforming systems (such as Linux, BSD, MacOS X):

```
rename("output.txt", "input.txt");
```

...or take a look at Boost.Filesystem for a portable solution.

Renaming will typically be an atomic operation for the file system, so you'll have the state before or after the transformation at all times, and if fecal matter hits the fan, you'll be able to repair it without too much trouble.

Comment: everything is working fine but what if the words "start" and "end" are combined with the others as 1 line without spaces in between for example like this line:     testteststarttestestend

Comment: Always on the same line, or potentially with line breaks between the tokens?

Comment: always on the same line

Comment: `std::size_t startpos = s.find(start_token); std::size_t endpos = s.find(end_token); if(endpos != std::string::npos && startpos + start_token.size() < endpos) { std::cout << s.substr(startpos + start_token.size(), endpos - startpos - start_token.size()) << std::endl; }`

Comment: your code helped me out very much so far .Now im facing a new problem with this same issue but this time there are line breaks .How can i achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

Filesystems in general do support "truncate" meaning to chop off the end, but they do not support removing the front of a file.  So you're left with only one option: you need to move the contents between "start" and "end" to the beginning of the file, then "truncate" the rest.  This isn't very efficient if the part you're moving is very large, but there's no way around it on typical filesystems.